# Conditional not working in Low Variables/Matrix field

Tags: matrix, low-variables

I have a simple Matrix field inside Low Variables. All I want to do is display a message when there are no results, but the conditional isn't working.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
{exp:low_variables:pair var="friends"}

    {if no_results}
         <p>Coming Soon</p>
    {/if}

<div class="span4">
    <ul class="span4 unstyled text-center">
       <li>{name}</li>
       <li>{special}</li>
       <li><a href="{link}">Website</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>

{/exp:low_variables:pair}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrix doesn't have a `no_results` variable. You'll have to just see if the LV field is empty instead. Try this.

```
{if '{exp:low_variables:pair var="friends"}{name}{exp:low_variables:pair}' == ''}
  <p>Coming soon.</p>
{/if}
{exp:low_variables:pair var="friends"}
  {name}
  {special}
{/exp:low_variables:pair}
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen, it almost worked, I just needed to change it to a single variable: {if '{exp:low_variables:parse var="friends"}' == ''}
  <p>Coming soon.</p>
{/if}

Comment: Cool. Glad you got it.